# How can i make the background image visible using css?

Tags: html, css

I tried to make the `div` with `background image` and with `text message`. In that Everything works perfect when i make the `width as 100%` and the `height as auto`. I make that div height is auto because whenever i increase the `font size of the text`  That div height is also dynamically increase. But Now my question is when i left empty message inside the div then it doesn't show any, Because of `height:auto` I want to show the div with actual background image appear-able. Even if i left message as empty. Is it possible to show the background image with height of auto.

Here is my code:

```
#loginContainer {
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background: url("http://s3.buysellads.com/1237708/176570-1371740695.gif") 
    no-repeat scroll center center #FF660D;  /*for example */
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-image: none;
    border-right: medium solid #FFFFFF;
    border-style: none solid solid;
    border-width: medium;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    vertical-align: super;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999999;
}
```

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a39Va/6/)**

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a39Va/7/)** with empty message inside div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a minimum height to the `div` like below:

```
#loginContainer {
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

[**Working Sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/a39Va/10/)

Comment: Thanks is it possible to make it as dynamic , I mean whatever image in background is shown in div is not possible without setting min-height:20px;

Comment: Thanks. without specifying the min-height is there is a way to get the actual background  size to show in div

Comment: Oh thanks for your time. 
@dharmesh give a suggestion to add the &nbsp; inside the div when i tried that also working, I still confuse which one is the correct way.?

Comment: @WordPress: I think setting the `min-height` to the image height as pointed out by Quentin is the best approach. `&nbsp;` will work, but I think it is more based on `line-height`. If `line-height` is 20px, it would show only 20px of background image. If it is not set, the default line height would be taken as value.

Comment: Thanks finally i did with min-height itself.

Answer (score 2):

Set a [`min-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-heights) equal to the height of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Set `min-height` to the #loginContainer

check the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/a39Va/12/

Answer (score 1):

just add an `&nbsp;`
if there is no content

```
 <div id="loginContainer">
&nbsp;
  <a class="" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Min-height will fail in IE6. You might want to consider adding the following:

```
#loginContainer {
  min-height: 200px;
}
* html #loginContainer { 
  height:200px; 
}
```

As IE6 is the only browser to recognise '* html ....' other browsers will just ignore it.

Unless you don't care about IE6! (I wish that was possible for me!)